# How do i get a zip file out of an xhr response?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm not very practiced in using XMLHttpRequests, but I am working on a drag and drop file converter that takes a zip file and returns one in response. Most of it is working, but I'm not sure how to pick the zip file out of the response. Here's where I'm at:

```
dropZone[0].ondrop = function(event) {
    // Stop the browser from opening the file in the window
    event.preventDefault();
    dropZone.removeClass('hover');

    // Get the file and the file reader
    var file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];

    // Send the file
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', uploadProgress, false);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(response) {
        if (event.target.readyState == 4) {
            alert("winner");
            if (event.target.status == 200) {
                $('#dropZone').text('Upload Complete!');

            }
            else {
                dropZone.text('Upload Failed!');
                dropZone.addClass('error');
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.open('POST', 'Home/handleFileUpload', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-FILE-NAME', file.name);
    xhr.send(file);
};
```

fiddler is showing a 200 with some binary results. How do I make the browswer save/download it as a zip?